# adding a rich text editor in next js with react-rte

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am trying to add a rich text editor in nextjs
what i choose is react-rte but i am getting error

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

i dont know what i did wrong i am trying to implement a simple rich text editor with
`h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6  and paragragh tag`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import RichTextEditor from "react-rte";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });

class MyStatefulEditor extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
  };

  state = {
    value: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue(),
  };

  onChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      // Send the changes up to the parent component as an HTML string.
      // This is here to demonstrate using `.toString()` but in a real app it
      // would be better to avoid generating a string on each change.
      this.props.onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <RichTextEditor value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/2-route-inspection-in-custom-app-forked-oynmrt?file=/components/MyStatefulEditor.js) for [the demo](https://oynmrt.sse.codesandbox.io/)

You can look into this code snippet with some comments

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//import the component lazily (not module itself)
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });

class MyStatefulEditor extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {}
   }

  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
  };

  //only trigger on the client-side
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    //import module on the client-side to get `createEmptyValue` instead of a component
    const module = await import("react-rte")
    this.setState({ 
        value: module.createEmptyValue(),
       })
  }

  onChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <RichTextEditor value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
}

export default MyStatefulEditor
```

[Function-based component version](https://codesandbox.io/s/2-route-inspection-in-custom-app-forked-oe5f53?file=/components/MyStatefulEditor.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//import the component
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });

const MyStatefulEditor = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const importModule = async () => {
      //import module on the client-side to get `createEmptyValue` instead of a component
      const module = await import("react-rte");
      setValue(module.createEmptyValue());
    };
    importModule();
  }, []);

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  return <RichTextEditor value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />;
};

MyStatefulEditor.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func
};

export default MyStatefulEditor;
```

Comment: @niku vu  tahnks for the answer it worked . but i want to store the data in database when i console.log(value) i am not getting the html data

Comment: i used the funtional compoenet

Comment: You need to `console.log(value.toString("html"))`. `value` itself is an object from `react-rte` @menucd

Answer (score -2):

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(
  () => import('react-rte'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
   6 | class MyStatefulEditor extends Component {
   7 |   static propTypes = {
>  8 |     onChange: PropTypes.func,
     |              ^
   9 |   };
  10 | 
  11 |   state = {

Comment: @menucd The answer is relevant (although it could use some supporting information). `react-rte` uses Web APIs so it needs to be dynamically imported on the client-side only to avoid errors when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server. The error you're getting is because `react` does not export `PropTypes`, that should come from the `prop-types` library, i.e. `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: @juliomalves i added the code u gave  now i am getting this error 'Module parse failed: Identifier 'PropTypes' has already been declared (5:7)'

Comment: You need to remove the `PropTypes` import from `react`.

Comment: @juliomalves i removed as u aked now getting ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you have `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` at the top of the file?

Comment: when i add   ` import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; `  at the top  i get  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. @juliomalves